# How to store struct type using spark cassandra connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have following JSON structure having employee details along with their address -

```
[
{"id" : 1000, "name" : "dev", "age" : 30, "address" : 
       {"city":"noida","state":"UP","pincode":"201201"}},
{"id" : 1001, "name" : "ravi", "age" : 36, "address" : 
       {"city":"noida","state":"UP","pincode":"201501"}} 
]
```

And I have this table in cassandra -

```
create table sparkdb.employee (id bigint, name text, age int, city text, state text, pincode text, primary key(id));
```

Now the question I have, how to store above JSON where the address is nested structType in employee table in Cassandra. ?

This is the code snipped I have -

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("CassandraConnectorIntegration")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()

val empDF = spark.read
  .option("multiline", true)
  .json(getClass.getResource("/sparksql/employee.json").getPath)

empDF.printSchema()

import spark.implicits._
val empDS = empDF.as[Employee]


empDS.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .option("confirm.truncate", "true") // this mode is required when using Overwrite mode
  .option("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
  .option("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
  .option("keyspace", "sparkdb")
  .option("table", "employee")
  .save()

}

case class Address(city: String, state: String, pincode: String)
case class Employee(id: Long, name: String, age: Long, address: Address)
```

Note- One way I know is to select the columns first with alias and then insert that dataframe, means -

```
empDS.createOrReplaceTempView("employee")
val empDF_out = spark.sql("select id, name, age, address.city city, address.state state, address.pincode pincode from employee")
empDF_out.write.format() .... ... ....
```

But this does not seem good to me, means if I have so many columns, then I have to select them individually first.

Comment: You would need to flatten the dataframe since the Cassandra table doesn't have a complex address column

Comment: How do I flatten this particular dataframes, is there any API or I have to define my own.

Comment: Seems like you already did it by selecting the respective columns

Comment: I do not want to do that way by selecting individual columns. So in case if nested struct has too many fields, then it does not seem nice to me.

Comment: You could store the address as a map in Cassandra, then it'll be one column

Comment: I was able to flatten the nested address column using normal dataset API i.e. val empDS = empDF.as[Employee].select("id","name","age","address.*"). But still the issue is I have to specify all other columns i.e. id, name, age. I will see how converting address as map would do that.